# read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1 error getting in xamarin android bluetooth connection

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, barcode-scanner, android-bluetooth

am using [barcode scanner via bluetooth](https://acaliaro.wordpress.com/2017/02/07/connect-a-barcode-reader-to-a-xamarin-forms-app-via-bluetooth/) documentation for reading barcode to my xamarin android project. but am getting the following error while establishing the socket connection "await BthSocket.ConnectAsync();"

**Error:**  ex  {Java.IO.IOException: read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1   at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+InstanceMethods.CallVoidMethod (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference instance, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0…}

I found several other questions about this issue in stackoverflow and other platforms, but most of them we're with solution written in Java or weren't applicable in my case.

Thanks in advance for help !